# Unable to change Panel Visibility

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a panel inside another panel. Now I need to alter inner panel's visibility based on certain condition. But I'm unable to change. It always remains to `False`. Here is the code I'm trying to:

```
PnlTagFolders.Visible = True 'Always remains False.
PnlTagFolders.BringToFront()
```

Here is the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: you are using an if statement, have you checked - just to be sure the code works until this line - if the else path is ever reached?

Comment: Is the parent `Panel` not visible (`.Visible = False`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a `Panel` visible if the parent `Panel` isn't visible. So make sure the parent `Panel` is visible (`.Visible = True`).

> `true` if the control and **all its child controls** are displayed; otherwise, false. The default is true.
>   *source:* [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visible#property-value)

See the following:

```
ChildPanel.Visible = False
ParentPanel.Visible = False
ChildPanel.Visible = True
Debug.Print(ChildPanel.Visible) 'False
```

Another example:

```
ChildPanel.Visible = False
ParentPanel.Visible = True
ChildPanel.Visible = True
Debug.Print(ChildPanel.Visible) 'True
```